# How to foreach multiple input in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a bit of problem on how to foreach multiple input using Laravel.

In my **Assigneecontroller**, I just use the simple query to pass it into blade. Here's my query

```
public function submit(Request $request){
    $assignees = DB::connection('oracle')
            ->table('ASSIGNEES')     
            ->orderBy('ASSIGNEES.ID','ASC')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();   

    return view('assignee',
            [ 
                'assignees'         => $assignees 
                    
            ]
        );
}
```

And in my **assignee.blade.php**, I populate the data like usual in my datatable. Plus, I use checkbox to select record that I want and update it in database. Here's my blade file

**assignee.blade.php**

```
<!-- List -->
    <div class="card card-default">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="card-actions">
                <a class="" data-action="collapse"><i class="ti-minus"></i></a>
            </div>
            <h4 class="card-title m-b-0">Assignee List</h4>  
        </div>
        <div class="card-body collapse show">  

            
            <form id='form-assignee' class="form-assignee" name="form-assignee" action="{{url('/updateAssignee')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf   
                
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" name="updateAssignees">Update Assignee</button>  

                <div class="table-responsive"> 
                    <table id="table-assignee" class="display wrap table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead style="background-color:#5b626b; color:#ffffff;">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="vertical-align:top;" rowspan="2">No</th>    
                                <th style="vertical-align:top;" rowspan="2">Selected</th>   
                                <th style="vertical-align:top;" rowspan="2">Assignee Name</th>    
                                <th style="vertical-align:top;" rowspan="2">Target</th>    
                            </tr>  
                            <tr style="background-color:#5b626b; color:#ffffff;"> 
                                <th style="background-color:#5b626b; color:#ffffff;">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="selection_all3" class="filled-in chk-col-green selection_all" name="selection_all[]" value=""/>
                                    <label for="selection_all"></label>
                                </th> 
                            </tr>
                        </thead> 
                        <tbody>   
                            <?php 
                                
                                foreach($assignees as $assignee){ 
                                    $parameter = $assignee->id;     
                                ?>  
                                    <tr>   
                                        <td><?php echo $count++; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $assignee->id; ?></td>
                                        <td>  
                                            <input 
                                                type="checkbox" 
                                                id="selection<?php echo $assignee->id; ?>" 
                                                class="filled-in chk-col-green selection_test selection<?php echo $assignee->id; ?>" 
                                                name="selection[]" 
                                                value="<?php echo $assignee->id; ?>
                                            "/>
                                            <label for="selection<?php echo $assignee->id; ?>"></label>
                                        </td> 
                                        <td> 
                                            <textarea id="assignee_name<?php echo $assignee->id; ?>" class="form-control textarealah assignee_name<?php echo $assignee->id; ?>" name="assignee_name[]" rows="1"><?php echo $assignee->assignee_email; ?></textarea> 
                                        </td>     
                                        <td> 
                                            <textarea id="main_target<?php echo $assignee->id; ?>" class="form-control textarealah main_target<?php echo $assignee->id; ?>" name="main_target[]" rows="1"><?php echo $assignee->main_target; ?></textarea> 
                                        </td>  
                                    </tr> 
                                <?php
                                }
                            ?>  
                        </tbody>   
                    </table> 
                </div> 
            </form>  
            
        </div>
    </div>  
<!-- List -->
```

I use jQuery to select all checkbox.

**jQuery file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selection_all').click(function(e) {  
        if(this.checked) { 
            $(".selection_test").each(function(){
                this.checked = true;
            });
        } else {
            $(".selection_test").each(function(){
                this.checked = false;
            });
        } 
    });   
});
```

And here's my **updateAssignee** function in my **Assigneecontroller**.

```
public function updateAssignee(Request $request){
    if(empty($request->get('selection'))){
        return json_encode(false);
    } else {
        $selects                    = $request->get('selection'); 
        $assignee_name              = $request->get('assignee_name');  
        $main_target                = $request->get('main_target');   

        foreach( $selects as $index => $select ) { 

            // print_r($select);

            $assignees = DB::connection('mysql')->table('ASSIGNEES')
                ->where('ID',$select)
                ->update(
                            [       
                                "ASSIGNEE"                => $assignee_name[$index],
                                "TARGET"                  => $main_target[$index]
                            ]
            );   
        }  
    }   
}
```

I don't understand why I can only update the first row. When I tried to select few record randomly using checkbox, it doesn't update the selected id in database. I **print_r($select)**, the value of **$assignee->id** display and working fine but failed to update the column with the new data.

What am I missing here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First check your selected checkbox is selected properly?

Comment: There is no id name `selection_all` in your view

Comment: @A.ANoman, yes. I have checked my selected checkbox and I can echo the selected checkbox it in my controller. The problem happen when I selected few checkbox. it failed to updated selected id/record. Data can only be updated if I select all checkbox.

Comment: @A.ANoman, oh . sorry . I updated the question.

Comment: use eloquent instead of raw database query, makes it easier for you

Comment: @ehsanasarzadeh, I already use DB eloquent in my controller